# The role of the preposition "in" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

> The moment he received the approval, Montgomerie began to look for his first collaborator, whom he found **in** Mahomed-i-Hameed, better known by his code name, the ‘Moonshee’. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=FAtu1wtDPJQC&pg=PT306&lpg=PT306&dq=The%20moment%20he%20received%20the%20approval,%20Montgomerie%20began%20to%20look%20for%20his%20first%20collaborator,%20whom%20he%20found%20**in**%20Mahomed-i-Hameed,%20better%20known%20by%20his%20code%20name,%20the%20%E2%80%98Moonshee%E2%80%99.&source=bl&ots=m42n2ubm92&sig=ebD0O2NZMXdtjpHmpne4wlkEX7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje7fTJ56HdAhWEZd8KHeTODa0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20moment%20he%20received%20the%20approval%2C%20Montgomerie%20began%20to%20look%20for%20his%20first%20collaborator%2C%20whom%20he%20found%20**in**%20Mahomed-i-Hameed%2C%20better%20known%20by%20his%20code%20name%2C%20the%20%E2%80%98Moonshee%E2%80%99.&f=false))

Mahomed-i-Hameed appears to be the name of a person, not a place, and the antecedent noun of the pronoun "whom". Then why is **in** used before the name of a person? What does it mean to "look for a person in a person"? I thought you could only look for a *quality/attribute* in a person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To find something in a person** is an idiom in English.

- He was searching the schools for a young, talented athlete and he found one in [name of person].
- She found her true companion in [name of person].

Comment: Not just a person, also a thing. I was looking for the ideal car for my grandmother and I found it in the Nissan Leaf. Mary was looking for a suitable novel to read and found one in _Great Expectations_.

Comment: Yes, but here the idiom is: to find something in someone. Sure, you can find something in something, too.

Comment: The basic form of the idiom is find _desired thing_ in _something_. That _something_ can be a person, a thing, a place, an idea, whatever.

Comment: Suppose we say the idiom is _to find something in someone or something._ Then would everyone be happy?